# "could not connect to control port"

Tags: mac

I cannot seem to figure this issue out. I just bought a brand new mac book air and have done nothing to it other than download Tor. Every time i go to run Tor, it says the same thing "cannot connect to control port". I'm running the newest OS X el capitan. I'm honestly not very tech savvy. someone please help, thank you

Comment: What version of Tor did you download? Could you explain a bit more in detail what you exactly did?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem. I can open the browser but I see this message on the home page every time I run it: "Something Went Wrong! Tor is not working in this browser."